# Can I install 18.04 on one partition while leaving original home folder intact on second partition?

Tags: partitioning

I've been auto-upgrading from 16.04 all the way up to the current release of 18.04, but with each update, especially from 17.04 (Unity) to 17.10 and 18.04 (GNOME), my OS has gotten a little more sluggish. So I'm thinking it might be time to do a fresh install of 18.04 via Live CD, which I haven't had to do in ages. I'm just wondering if, when I choose the **Something Else** option in the installer, I can replace just my current / partition without touching my separate /home partition. I've seen older posts for previous versions of Ubuntu, but I just want to know if protocol is still the same today as it was back in 2011 or 2012.

Comment: You want to mount your /home as part of the new install. But must NOT check the format box. Always have good backups as then you do not have to worry about issues. Also if system and current install is UEFI be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode, or is system is BIOS boot installer in BIOS. As how you boot install media is then how it installs.

Comment: @oldfred Could you test it by installing 18.04 to a new partition and linking it to existing `/home`? I have an integrated home and boot with `/` so haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I installed Kubuntu this way yesterday (had gnome before), no problems. As @oldfred said, make sure you only check the *format* box on the `/` partition.

Comment: I do not think I ever used a separate /home. I do use /mnt/data for all my data as I want all data in all my installs. Back when I first started with Ubuntu I had a /mnt/shared NTFS data partition, but that is now long gone.

Answer (score 0):

I did this very thing to upgrade several boxes from 16.04 and one from 14.04 to 18.04. It works!

The procedure I used:

Choose Something Else install

On partition screen:

- **Double click system partition**
- Use as Ext4 journaling file system
- Format the partition
- Mount point /
- **Double click home partition**
- Use as Ext4 journaling file system
- DO NOT Format the partition
- Mount point /home
- **Double click swap partition**
- Just make sure it says use as swap area